# How does a pseudorandom generator produce a similar distribution to $U_{n}$?

Tags: stream-cipher, randomness, pseudo-random-generator, pseudo-random-function

According to Wikipedia, a function ${\displaystyle G:\{0,1\}^{\ell }\to \{0,1\}^{n}}$ with ${\displaystyle \ell < n}$ is a pseudorandom generator against $\mathcal {A}$ with bias $\epsilon$  if, for every $A$ in ${\mathcal {A}}$, the statistical distance between the distributions $A(G(U_\ell))$ and $A(U_n)$ is at most $\epsilon$ , where $U_{k}$ is the uniform distribution on $\{0,1\}^{k}$.

My question is that if $\ell < n$, then $|G(U_{\ell})|$ < $|U_{n}|$. How can these distributions be so similar (i.e., have an error $\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is very small)? Shouldn't they differ very much as the number of elements in $U_{n}$ are at least twice as much as those in $G(U_{\ell})$?

Comment: Welcome to cryptoSE! In the definition, the statistical distance is not  between $G(U_l)$ and $U_n$ but between $A(G(U_l))$ and $A(U_n)$. The distinction is crucial because we are only asking that $\mathcal A$ differentiates with probability at most $\epsilon$. I hope this helps

Comment: @MarcIlunga is correct, and I’ll just add that typically we require $A$ to output a single bit (representing its “decision” about whether its input was drawn from $G(U_l)$ or $U_n$). So, the statistical difference in your question is merely the difference between the probabilities that $A$ outputs 1 in the two cases.